# Angular - Ngx-org-chart style not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using the [ngx-org-chart](https://github.com/MuminCelal/ngx-org-chart) in my proyect with Angular. The problem is that styles aren't working.

My steps were the following:

1. I have installed the package:

> yarn add ngx-org-chart

2. Then, I added the ngx-org-chart imports to angular.json styles block

   ```
   "styles": [ 
             "node_modules/ngx-org-chart/_theming.scss",
             "src/styles.scss"
   ],
   ```

With only this, it doesn't working. Then, I also tried the below:

1. I have imported the styles in styles.scss with the below:

```
import '~ngx-org-chart/_theming.scss'
```

But the styles aren't working. Can anyone help me?. Thank you

**Edit**

In my component, I have the next code line to use the library:

```
<ngx-org-chart [nodes]="nodes" direction="vertical"></ngx-org-chart>
```

And nodes is:

```
nodes: any = [
    {
      name: 'Sundar Pichai',
      cssClass: 'ngx-org-ceo',
      image: '',
      title: 'Chief Executive Officer',
      childs: [
        {
          name: 'Thomas Kurian',
          cssClass: 'ngx-org-ceo',
          image: 'assets/node.svg',
          title: 'CEO, Google Cloud',
        },
        {
          name: 'Susan Wojcicki',
          cssClass: 'ngx-org-ceo',
          image: 'assets/node.svg',
          title: 'CEO, YouTube',
          childs: []
        },
        {
          name: 'Jeff Dean',
          cssClass: 'ngx-org-head',
          image: 'assets/node.svg',
          title: 'Head of Artificial Intelligence',
          childs: [
            {
              name: 'David Feinberg',
              cssClass: 'ngx-org-ceo',
              image: 'assets/node.svg',
              title: 'CEO, Google Health',
              childs: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },       
];
```

And, in app.module.ts, I have:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmptyRouteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    ThemeModule,
    I18NextModule.forRoot(),
    NgxOrgChartModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**Edit 2**

When styles don't work, the chart sees so:

[image]

But it should see something like this:

[image]

Versions:

- ngx-org-chart: 1.1.1
- Angular: 11.0.5

Comment: After importing styles, how have you used component, can you add that in the description? Please verify if you have imported NgxOrgChartModule too

Comment: @Tejeshree I have already edited the description. Thank you for the issue

Comment: Thanks for the update. Also, what is the exact issue, like you said styles are not working?

Comment: Thank you. I have added two pictures. One of them is how I see it and the other is how should be @Tejeshree . You can see that it haven't got any connector.

Comment: Thanks, I have added an answer after trying it for myself.

Answer (score 2):

I added `@import '~ngx-org-chart/_theming';` in `styles.scss`.

Imported `import { NgxOrgChartModule } from 'ngx-org-chart';` in `app.module.ts` as

```
    @NgModule({
        imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, NgxOrgChartModule],
```

In html:

```
<ngx-org-chart [nodes]="nodes" direction="vertical" ></ngx-org-chart>
```

Assets are not available as i didn't import them

[image]

Comment: Can you share your stackoverflow, please?

Comment: Along with this I had to add "node_modules/ngx-org-chart/_theming.scss" in angular.json as @yoonus mentioned in below answer. It worked after that!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your styles.css :
import '../node_modules/ngx-org-chart/_theming.scss';

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what said in documentation
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-org-chart

Adding this angular.json in

```
 styles: [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/ngx-org-chart/_theming.scss"
        ],
```

worked for me